# What does "R F D" stand for in a city directory?

Tags: united-states, address, missouri, abbreviations, directories

I've seen several entries in different cities of the Missouri area that use the abbreviation of `R F D` sometimes followed by a numeral for the address of a person.

What does `R F D` stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RFD = Rural Free Delivery, referring to those people on the rural mail routes. The numeral will refer to the route.

The abbreviation is noted in the introductory information of a [1914 Missouri directory](http://freepages.history.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~cappscreek/directory.html).

Wikipedia also provides a good overview of [Rural Free Delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rural_Free_Delivery).

> Rural Free Delivery (RFD) is a service which began in the United
>   States in the late 19th century, to deliver mail directly to rural
>   farm families. Prior to RFD, individuals living in more remote
>   homesteads had to pick up mail themselves at sometimes distant post
>   offices or pay private carriers for delivery.

Comment: I edited your answer to add a quote from the beginning of the Wikipedia article to give the historical context for the introduction of RFD.

Comment: Similar abbreviations are RD (Rural Delivery) & RR (Rural Route). One of the more famous RFD locales is Mayberry, of the 1960's TV series.